# How do I allow someone else to update a chrome app I've uploaded to the Chrome web store?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Once I've uploaded a chrome application to the web store, how do I go about allowing someone else access to update/modify it?

Comment: Sadly, this question -- while perfectly reasonable -- is off-topic for Stack Overflow.